# Selecting Maximum number of concurrent records based on timeStart and timeEnd values

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have an SQL Table in an Oracle server containing values of the start and end time of an event and want to know what is the maximum number of concurrent events happening in the same second via an SQL Query if possible.

My table structure is:

```
EventID    StartTime   EndTime
===================================
12345      10:25:50    10:25:59
12346      10:25:51    10:26:00
12347      10:25:55    10:26:10
```

I have tried making a query selecting the hour, minute and second as separate fields and group the records by them but since I have time ranges I don't know how to check when they overlap (since they are being executed concurrently if they have overlapping time).

If it is not possible as a query, can you recommend me an efficient way to calculate this data in Java? I can think of a way by looping the ResultSet but don't know exactly how to permute the overlapping events.

Comment: which RDBMS are you using?  it seems like you should be able to use a LAG function on rows ordered by StartTime and see if the next start time is earlier than the previous start time + (endTime-StartTime)

Comment: Not sure lag works here as they are independent but overlapping records? (And it's tagged for Oracle)

Comment: By overlapping records I mean records that are happening at the same second, even when their start and end times are not the same. Ex: In the sample table I put in the question the three records overlap because they all were running in the lapse from `10:25:55` to `10:25:59`

Comment: If you had a record from 10:25:50 to 10:25:51, and one from 10:25:51 to 10:25:52, would you consider those to be overlapping? Both include second 51 if you treat it as inclusive, but you might not.

Comment: In my case I consider the boundaries inclusive. So in your example both records would overlap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a list of all the times with an increment -- +1 when an event starts and -1 when an event ends.

Then use a cumulative sum to get the total active at any time and pull the maximum value:

```
with times as (
      select starttime as t, +1 as inc
      from structure
      union all
      select endtime, -1
      from structure
     )
select t.*
from (select t, sum(inc) over (order by t) as actives
      from (select t, sum(inc) as inc
            from times
            group by t
           ) t
      order by actives desc
    ) t
where rownum = 1;
```

The innermost subquery (with the `group by`) is just to handle things that happen at exactly the same time.

Comment: Your query works very well. Thanks! IT even avoids using too much oracle specific syntax

Comment: @RobertoLinares . . . Should also perform much better than the other answer.

Comment: Nice (now I've got my head around what it's doing *8-). It doesn't catch periods overlapping by a single second though ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e17ba/1)]); I guess the positive and negative inc at that moment cancel each other out?

Comment: ... assuming that is *supposed* to count as an overlap, which it may not. Also completely agree about the performance aspect.

Comment: @Alex . . . The OP needs to define what happens in the boundary case when the times are the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
package test3;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class maximumnumbercheck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
int a,b;

        System.out.println("Enter A Value");
Scanner max=new Scanner(System.in);
a=max.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter B Value");
b=max.nextInt();


max.close();


String msg=(a>=b)? "  A is Maximum NUmber " :"  b Is Maximum Number";
System.out.println("msg  "+msg);
    }

}
```