# Split 2 db rows into 3 by date ranges

Tags: oracle

I have a problem I can't solve. I have A and B money which I can spend in a defined period. These are the following two rows in the DB (with begin_date, end_date and amount columns):

- A: 2015.01.01.-2015.09.30. 10.000$
- B: 2015.07.01.-2015.12.31.  7.000$

So these dates are overlapped, and it means I can spend more money between 2017.07.01. and 2015.09.30. So in the output I have to get the following:

- 2015.01.01.-2015.07.01. x$
- 2015.07.01.-2015.09.30. y$
- 2015.09.30.-2015.12.31. z$

How can I select these ranges and count the amounts considering I spend money equally per months? If I can define the 3 date ranges I think I can count the amounts, but the dates are really tricky, and I can't handle them.

I use Oracle 11g.

Comment: What is the rule for the amounts - prorate by #days?  What if there are 4 records, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Borrowing heavily from [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30518868/266304), which is also explained [here](http://sqlmag.com/blog/solutions-packing-date-and-time-intervals-puzzle) in more detail along with some alternatives, to just get the date ranges you can do:

```
with cte1 as
(
  select begin_date as marker_date, 1 as type
  from your_table
  union all
  select end_date + 1 as marker_date, -1 as type
  from your_table
),
cte2 as (
  select marker_date as begin_date,
    lead(marker_date) over (order by marker_date) - 1 as end_date,
    sum(type) over (order by marker_date) as periods
  from cte1
)
select begin_date, end_date from cte2
where end_date is not null and periods > 0;
```

Which gives you:

```
BEGIN_DATE END_DATE 
---------- ----------
2015-01-01 2015-06-30
2015-07-01 2015-09-30
2015-10-01 2015-12-31
```

I've assumed that you don't actually want the generated periods to overlap by a day, and instead want them to be the start and ends of months like the original two rows.

To get the amounts - if I've understood what you described - you can modify that to include the amount change at each date, as either positive or negative depending on whether it's the start or end of a period:

```
with cte1 as
(
  select begin_date as marker_date,
    amount / months_between(end_date + 1, begin_date) as monthly_amount
  from your_table
  union all
  select end_date + 1 as marker_date,
    -amount / months_between(end_date + 1, begin_date) as monthly_amount
  from your_table
),
cte2 as (
  select marker_date as begin_date,
    lead(marker_date) over (order by marker_date) - 1 as end_date,
    sum(monthly_amount) over (order by marker_date) as total_monthly_amount
  from cte1
)
select begin_date, end_date,
  total_monthly_amount * months_between(end_date + 1, begin_date) as amount
from cte2
where end_date is not null and total_monthly_amount > 0;

BEGIN_DATE END_DATE       AMOUNT
---------- ---------- ----------
2015-01-01 2015-06-30 6.66666667
2015-07-01 2015-09-30 6.83333333
2015-10-01 2015-12-31        3.5
```

This works by dividing the amount for the original period by the number of months it covers:

```
select begin_date as marker_date, amount,
  months_between(end_date + 1, begin_date) as months,
  amount / months_between(end_date + 1, begin_date) as monthly_amount
from your_table
union all
select end_date + 1 as marker_date, amount,
  months_between(end_date + 1, begin_date) as months,
  -amount / months_between(end_date + 1, begin_date) as monthly_amount
from your_table;

MARKER_DATE     AMOUNT     MONTHS MONTHLY_AMOUNT
----------- ---------- ---------- --------------
2015-01-01          10          9     1.11111111
2015-07-01           7          6     1.16666667
2015-10-01          10          9    -1.11111111
2016-01-01           7          6    -1.16666667
```

And then using that as a CTE and applying the lead analytic function to reconstruct the new, non-overlapping periods:

```
with cte1 as
(
  select begin_date as marker_date,
    months_between(end_date + 1, begin_date) as months,
    amount / months_between(end_date + 1, begin_date) as monthly_amount
  from your_table
  union all
  select end_date + 1 as marker_date,
    months_between(end_date + 1, begin_date) as months,
    -amount / months_between(end_date + 1, begin_date) as monthly_amount
  from your_table
)
select marker_date as begin_date,
  lead(marker_date) over (order by marker_date) - 1 as end_date,
  sum(monthly_amount) over (order by marker_date) as total_monthly_amount,
  months_between(lead(marker_date) over (order by marker_date), marker_date) as months
from cte1;

BEGIN_DATE END_DATE   TOTAL_MONTHLY_AMOUNT     MONTHS
---------- ---------- -------------------- ----------
2015-01-01 2015-06-30           1.11111111          6
2015-07-01 2015-09-30           2.27777778          3
2015-10-01 2015-12-31           1.16666667          3
2016-01-01                      0.00000000
```

And finally excluding the artificial open-ended period at the end, plus any that have a zero total in case there are any gaps (which you don't have in the small sample, but could appear in a larger data set); and multiplying the new monthly amount by the number of months in the new period.

Comment: OMG, you're my savior, this is exactly what I needed!